# return json object to index.html and render data to dataTable columns

Tags: python, django

I want to use dataTable to render data to its columns in index.html after I login to my site . dataTable does not show any data. I knew my issue is in views.py, since I want to return json object to index.html. When I use HttpReponse to return json object, it correctly returned json object as in format below but not in index.html. My approach is that I want to return json object to index.html and render data in dataTable columns. Any helps will be highly appreciated!!

views.py

```
@login_required
def index(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
                #if (Employee.objects.filter(emp_type__contains = "user").filter(user__username__contains = request.user.username)):
                if (Employee.objects.filter(Q(emp_type__icontains = "user") | Q(emp_primary__icontains = 2)).filter(user__username__icontains = request.user.username)):
                        projects = Project.objects.filter(user__id__icontains = request.user.id)
                        '''paginator = Paginator(projects, 16)
                        page = request.GET.get("page")
                        try:
                                projects = paginator.page(page)
                        except PageNotAnInteger:
                                projects = paginator.page(1)
                        except EmtyPage:
                                projects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                        '''
                        data = serializers.serialize("json", projects)
                        output = [d['fields'] for d in json.loads(data)]

                        #return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {"data": data})
                        #return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'projects': projects})
                        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
                elif (Employee.objects.filter(emp_type__contains = "admin").filter(user__username__contains = request.user.username)):
                        projects = Project.objects.all()
                        '''paginator = Paginator(projects, 16)
                        page = request.GET.get("page")
                        try:
                                projects = paginator.page(page)
                        except PageNotAnInteger:
                                projects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                        '''
                        data = serializers.serialize("json", projects)
                        output = [d['fields'] for d in json.loads(data)]

                        #return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'projects': projects})
                        #return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {"data": data})
                        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
    else:
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {})
```

====
index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% load static  %}
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'polls/style.css'%}" type = "text/css"> -->
    </head>

    {% block body %}
    <div class = "container">

    <form action="/ajax/validate_username/" id="post-form" method="POST" style="width=1150px">
    {% csrf_token  %}
    <div class = "pagination">
            <input type = "text" id = "talk"></input>
            <form>
            <table class = "table table-hover table-dark" id="project_table">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                    <th>Project No</th>
                                    <th>Project Section</th>
                                    <th>Project Description</th>
                                    <th>Project ID</th>
                                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                                    <th>Funding Year</th>
                            </tr>
                             <!-- <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search_no" id="no_id"  placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search_section" id="section_id" placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search" id = "search1" placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search_id" id="project_id"  placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search_name" id="employee_id"  placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                                    <th scope="col" ><input type = "text" name = "search_year" id="funding_id"  placeholder = "Search"><input type="submit"></input></input></th>
                            </tr> -->
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                    <th>Project No</th>
                                    <th>Project Section</th>
                                    <th>Project Description</th>
                                    <th>Project ID</th>
                                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                                    <th>Funding Year</th>
                            </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                    <!-- { if projects %}
                            { for project in projects%}
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>{project.pro_no}} </td>
                                            <td scope = "row"><a href = "{ url 'emp_detail' project.id %}">{project.pro_section}}</a></td>
                                            <td>{project.pro_description}}</td>
                                            <td>{project.pro_ID}}</td>
                                            <td>{project.pro_description}}</td>
                                            <td>{project.pro_ID}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                    { for emp in project.employee.all  %}
                                                    <table>
                                                            <tr><td>{emp.first_name}}</td></tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    { endfor  %}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                    { for emp in project.employee.all  %}
                                                    <table>
                                                            <tr><td>{emp.funding_year}}</td></tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    { endfor %}
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                            { endfor %}
                    { endif %} 
                     <span class = "step-links">
                            { if projects.has_previous %}
                                    <i class = "fa fa-angle-double-left" style="color:black"></i>
                                    <a href = "?page={projects.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a>
                            { endif %}
                            <span class = "current">
                                    Page {projects.number}} of {projects.paginator.num_pages}}.
                            </span>
                            { if projects.has_next %}
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="color:black"></i>
                                    <a class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="color:black" href = "?page={projects.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
                            { endif %}
                    <span>  -->
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
    </div>

    </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
            <!--  <script src="/static/scripts/main.js"></script> -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                            console.log("search function is working!");
                            $("#project_table").dataTable({
                                    "processing": false,
                                    "ajax": {
                                            "processing": false,
                                            "url": "{% url 'index' %}",
                                            "dataSrc": ""
                                    },
                                    "columns": [
                                            {"data": "fields.pro_description"},
                                            {"data": "pk"}
                                    ]
                            });
                    });
            </script>

{% endblock %}
```

==
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import(
        login, logout, password_reset, password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm,
        password_reset_complete
)
from django.contrib.auth.views import(
        PasswordResetView,
        PasswordResetDoneView,
        PasswordResetConfirmView,
        PasswordResetCompleteView
)
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .import views

from .import forms

#app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [

        #url(r'^$', views.index_.as_view(), name = 'index'),
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/emp_detail/$', views.emp_detail, name = 'emp_detail'),
        url(r'^search/$', views.search, name = 'search'),
        url(r'^project_working/$', views.project_working_detail, name = 'project_working_detail'),
        url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'polls/login.html'}, name = 'login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name':'polls/logout.html'}, name = 'logout'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register, name = 'register'),

        url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
        url(r'^ajax/validate_username/$', views.validate_username, name = 'validate_username'),
        #url(r'^ajax/object/$', views.Object.as_view(), name = 'object'),

        url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name = 'reset_password'),
        url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name = 'password_reset_done'),
        url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
        url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', password_reset_complete, name = 'password_reset_complete'),

        url(r'^renew/$', views.renew_book_librarian, name = 'renew_book_librarian'),
]
```

==json object

```
[{"model": "polls.project", "pk": 2, "fields": {"user": 1, "pro_no": "9.1", "pro_section": "9.1 ABC", "pro_description": "SUPPORT ABCDE", "pro_ID": "001332-H", "percent": 0.04, "employee": [1]}}, {"model": "polls.project", "pk": 5, "fields": {"user": 1, "pro_no": "9.1", "pro_section": "9.1 ABC", "pro_description": "SUPPORT ABCDE FY-20", "pro_ID": "2014", "percent": 0.02, "employee": [1]}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really seperate some of that logic away from the index view. If you notice you are doing an AJAX request for the JSON data for the datatable. So you should create a different URL that handles returning that data for the AJAX request. This will clean up your index view and also separate the data from the page which asks for data.

For example "/index" will return the literal index.html page and then that page can query "/index/projects" or more generically "/projects" which returns the JSON object for all the different projects you want. With this approach you can also have more pages get this data without having to repeat yourself in their view logic which keeps your code DRY and easy to read.

Side note: In python comment out code using # instead of triple quotes, it is standard to use # for commenting out code while triple quotes is meant more for multiline strings and doc creation.

Also in future questions try to only post the code that is directly relevant to the error so that people answering don't have to read as much.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer! I modified my code to separate AJAX part and it worked as expected.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, my last question is that my json object contains "employee": [1]. I had tried Deserialization of natural keys to get first_name and last_name instead of employee id. but json object still remains in same way. I can upload my models.py if needed.

Comment: To be clear, the json object has the field employee which has the value of an integer id and you want it to have the value of another object containing the first and last name?

Comment: yes, my json object has employee field which has the value of an integer. I want to get employee name instead of an integer. I had tried Deserialization of natural keys, but it didnt work. Json object is still same. You can take a look at my json object which I had posted above.

Comment: I think I might need to see the serializer function being used and model

Comment: I had resolved that issue, I got returned json as format below, I would like to access employee first name. I had tried fields.employee[0][0] (since that was nested array of dictionary) and fields.employee[0]. but neither of them worked.

Comment: [{"model": "polls.project", "pk": 2, "fields": {"user": jnguyen, "pro_no": "9.1", "pro_section": "9.1 ABC", "pro_description": "SUPPORT ABCDE", "pro_ID": "001332-H", "percent": 0.04, "employee": [["ABC", "DEFG"]]}}]
that is my json format, since it didnt return first_name and last_last, so I cant access fields.employee[0].first_name

Comment: Did you convert the JSON string to an object in the html/js code? Becuase with that obj the access obj[0].fields.employee[0][0] should work. You could try doing obj[0]["fields"]["employees"][0][0]

Comment: it really confused me, since I didnt convert returned json string to object but I can still access to fields.pro_section and pro_description to display them to dataTable columns. After I deserialization and Serialization I got expected returned json. but can not access [fields][employee][name]

Comment: I didnt convert returned json to object in html/js. I could really appreciate if you could instruct in more details.

Comment: I had resolved that issue by doing fields.employee[0][0]. My question is why I did not convert returned json string to object but I can still access it as an object? Thanks in advance.